# Is there any way to use command line arguments to decide how my program will start in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make CRUD application which can work 2 different ways:

1. Console application (store "Customer" data to text file)
2. GUI application (store "Customer" data to Database)

I want to use command line argument as a variable to choose between these 2 interfaces.

For example:

```
if(args[0] == 0){
    startAppWithGUI();
}
else{
    startAppWithConsole();
}
```

but I'm so confused that where my `main` method is using that arguments. All I can see is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a Launcher

```java
import javafx.application.Application;

public class Launcher{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      if(args[0] != 0){
         Application.launch(YourFXMainClass.class,args);
       }else{
         YourConsoleApplication.main(args);
      }

   }
}
```

And then you use the Launcher as Main Class